# Printing Gridview

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

to print my Gridview i used following event Button_Print_Click. below is my code:

```
private void Button_Print_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.PagerSettings.Visible = false;
    GridView1.DataSource = DataLoad();
    GridView1.DataBind();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    GridView1.RenderControl(hw);
    string gridHTML = sw.ToString().Replace("\"", "'").Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
    sb.Append("window.onload = new function(){");
    sb.Append("var printWin = window.open('', '', 'left=0");
    sb.Append(",top=0,width=1000,height=600,status=0');");
    sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");
    sb.Append(gridHTML);
    sb.Append("\");");
    sb.Append("printWin.document.close();");
    sb.Append("printWin.focus();");
    sb.Append("printWin.print();");
    sb.Append("printWin.close();};");
    sb.Append("</script>");
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "GridPrint", sb.ToString());
    GridView1.DataSource = DataLoad();
    GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

But by focusing  the page, it doesn't show the css properties. For example my GridViewHeader text font looks simple but not bold!! is there anything wrong with the code? Why dont I get the original CSS styled page printed?

Please help thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling a pop-up using window.open(), this popup opens a new HTML page, and even if you inject javascript generated HMTL in it, it doesn't have any reference to your CSS file.
Try to add a link to it in the string output

```
sb.Append("printWin.document.write(\"");
sb.Append("<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='...your.css'>")
sb.Append(gridHTML);
```

Note that this is really an odd way to print a html page, I would find it more simple to generate a extra Print CSS for this using the @media rules, and call the javascript print() on the very same page : see eg http://edutechwiki.unige.ch/en/CSS_for_print_tutorial

Comment: thank you for ur quick answer !but  with the below method i need to print only the gridview,  ur suggested method prints the whole page with buttons, i must use the media rules of css to avoid showing buttons. Anyway i ll try both and look . thank u!

Comment: The basic trick with using @media print css is to hide everything but the part you want. Put the HTML parts that as buttons in some panel with css class, and hide this class for print using the display: none rule.